# Collections.sort on list of object java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I'm need to make sure i understand correctly someone else code at work 
this block sort this object:  theObjectList
by the variable getId()
what do i need to do in order to add another variable to the sorting ? for example getName()

```
    protected void fillData(List<AnyObject> theObjectList) {
        Collections.sort(theObjectList, (A, B) -> A.getId() - B.getId());
/*  more code */
}
```

Comment: You need to use it. It is already obvious that `A` and `B` are the compared instances, so it should be obvious that you need `A.getName()` and `B.getName()`.

Comment: How would the full line will look like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Comparators.comparing

```
Collections.sort(theObjectList, 
                 Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getId()).andThen(x -> x.getName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Believe you'd need to understand and pickup [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach5) expressions. They have been introduced since [jdk8](https://dzone.com/articles/using-lambda-expression-sort).